# Draw on image from cvShowImage

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

using Visual Studio 2012; c++; openCV.
I show an image using cvShowImage, it gives me a window.
I want draw a form with mouse(a rectangle for exemple) on the image including in this window !!

Comment: Who put an upvote  ?

Comment: regarding to your question, make it clear what is your problem, what have to tried to do.

Comment: is it clear now? sorry, I've a problem with expression

Comment: 1.) please avoid functions like cvShowImage(), but use cv::imshow() and cv::Mat.. 2.) [RTFM](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html#drawing-1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer berak, but what I want to do is drawing with mouse !

Comment: have you tried anything for your problem ? at least searching in SO, Google etc ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, what I found is some solution for an auto drawing, or a manual drawing with specification of the position of the form.

Comment: And there's some solutions with WindowsForm; which is out of my subject !

Comment: Have you really used Google? http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut3.html#Step%201

Answer (score 1):

Use the SetMouseCallback function to setup a callback for mouse events. Capture the vents and draw what you like to a cvImage and show the updated image in the same window.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html